# converting string to Float in talend , For input "64,5" error

Tags: java, type-conversion, talend, data-conversion, converters

I have done these steps for each excel file and it works fine until I can't figure out why this error keeps appearing when converting the string to float in this file.
I was using Taggregate directly and when the error appeared, I found that some people have solved this problem by using Tconvertype but the same error keeps appearing.

[image]

[image]
This is the error

[image]

after using

```
Float.valueOf(row.fieldName.replace(',', '.'))
```

some values successfully get converted the other cause an error like the first

```
For input "0.5"
```

using a point not a comma in the error this time . Any solution.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Tmap

```
Float.valueOf(row.fieldName.replace(',', '.'))
```

Changing the comma  `(,)` to point `(.)` solved my problem, although I had no problem converting the string containing the comma in the last file. So if anyone has an explanation for this?

Comment: This solution is not efficient

Comment: Maybe changing the type of your output would solve your problem (double) . Or get the reject  of your output to see what it is going in your reject .

Comment: Other thing , changing the the comma (,) to point (.)  would not solve the problem because A Float does not contain either a . nor a ,. It holds purely the numeric value that it represents.

The choice of formatting it with a . or a , is made at the point where you transform it into a String.   And use something like DecimalFormat to produce that String.

Comment: public static String commaFloat(Float yourValue){
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
    nf.setGroupingUsed(false);
    return nf.format(yourValue);
}

Comment: put this in your routine and test it with a tjava call